# Adaptive Threshold in OpenCV (Version 1 - the swig version)

Tags: python, opencv, beagleboard

I'm trying to get adaptive thresholding working in the python binding to opencv 
(the swig one - cannot get opencv 2.0 working as I am using a [beagleboard](http://www.beagleboard.org) as the cross compiling is not working yet).  I have a greyscale image (ccg.jpg) and the following code

```
import opencv
from opencv import highgui
img = highgui.cvLoadImage("ccg.png")
img_bw = opencv.cvCreateImage(opencv.cvGetSize(img), opencv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1)
opencv.cvAdaptiveThreshold(img, img_bw, 125, opencv.CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, opencv.CV_THRESH_BINARY, 7, 10)
```

When I run this I get the error:

```
RuntimeError:  openCV Error:
    Status=Formats of input arguments do not match
    function name=cvAdaptiveThreshold
    error messgae=
    file_name=cvadapthresh.cpp
    line=122
```

I've also tried having both the source and dest arguments both the same (greyscale) and I get the error

> Unsupported format or combination of formats

Does anyone have any clues as to where I could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a user of the swig interface, but in C the `cvLoadImage` function loads an image as 3 channel RGB by default, so if that's true for swig as well, then you're going to need to either change your code to load `img` as grayscale (`CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE`) or do an intermediate step to convert it to grayscale with `cvCvtColor`.

Comment: hello thanks for that - I indeed needed to convert the loaded image to greyscale and then it worked fine for me - onto the next challenge :)